# how can I decode base64 to .jpg

Tags: php, laravel, image, base64

I can decode `base64` to `PNG`, but when I try to decode to `JPG` I got the problem.

**Code to decode png**

```php
$image = $request['profile_image'];  // your base64 encoded
$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imageName = 'aaaa'.'.'.'png';
\File::put(public_path() .'/admin_assets/assets/images/users/' . $imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

**Code decode to jpg**

```php
$image = $request['profile_image'];  // your base64 encoded
$image = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imageName = 'aaaa'.'.'.'jpg';
\File::put(public_path() .'/admin_assets/assets/images/users/' . $imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

The result from the second code 
http://prnt.sc/oysxqn

Comment: Are you sure that the jpeg image contains the string `'data:image/jpeg;base64,'`?

Comment: no, and what I should do?

Comment: Check that your `$request['profile_image']` contains `'data:image/jpeg;base64,'`, it's only a `if()`, in case return an error.

Comment: I wrote a function for that. Check it out -> https://github.com/jokerrs/base64_decode_image/blob/master/base64_decode_image.php

Comment: I see 'data:image/png;base64' when I uploading jpg, but I want to see original format image, How can I do it?

Comment: Thank you very much, and can you answer in this question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701710/output-image-is-always-png-croppie-not-keeping-original-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function for that [base64_decode_image()](https://github.com/jokerrs/base64_decode_image/blob/master/base64_decode_image.php) (It's GitHub link I wrote a function)

Function return array (file and type), but if is image format not allowed it fill return `false`.

**Usage**

```php
$AllowedFormats = array('jpg', 'png'); // Here we declare allowed formats

$ProfilImage = $request['profile_image'];

$Image = base64_decode_image($ProfilImage, $AllowedFormats);

// Here we checking if is returned array or not
if(!is_array($Image )){
   echo 'Wrong image format';
   die(); // if is image format not allowed it will stop scrip and throw an error
}

$type = $Image['type']; // type is file extension as well
$DecodedImage = $Image['file']; // Decoded image file

$ImageName = 'whet-every-you-wanna.'.$type;

// Then you can upload your image
\File::put(public_path() .'/admin_assets/assets/images/users/' . $imageName, $DecodedImage);
```

Comment: ok, but when I upload a jpg image base64  give me data:image/png;base64 if you want I can show my jquery code!