# Output Image is always PNG , croppie not keeping original Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, croppie

Output Image is always PNG, croppie not keeping original Format.

I use croppie library
I want to get the original image extension, but I got or jpeg or png.

```
                vanilla.result({
                    type: 'base64',
                    format: 'jpeg',
                    size: 'original'
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    $('.cr-boundary').hide();
                    $('.cr-slider-wrap').hide();
                    $('#hidden_image_input').val(resp);
                    $('#profile_image').attr('src', resp);
                    $('#profile_image').show();

                });
```

Comment: it should not be a problem at all, change upload extension it prevents you from facing security issues, because a malicious user could upload a malicious script and get accesss into your system, you should always validate files on backend.

Comment: Guess you’ll need to determine what format your image is up front, so that you can specify the `format` parameter accordingly.

Comment: enableExif: true whiles initializing will give you access to the metadata of the file you are uploading; you will need the Exif.js file loaded see: http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/#enableExif